# Get the negative of an Optional Chain

Tags: ios, swift, optional-chaining

This is not allowed (bad expression)

```
if !(let nsDictionaryObject = swiftObject as? NSDictionary)
{
    "Error could not make NSDictionary in \(self)"
    return
}
```

Is it possible to check for the negative of an Optional Chain expression in 1 line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, you can use

```
guard let nsDictionaryObject = swiftObject as? NSDictionary else {
    "Error could not make NSDictionary in \(self)"
    return
}
```

This will also bind `nsDictionaryObject` to the scope outside the guard statement.

Comment: I will definitely try this when I upgrade to 2.0 thanks.

Comment: Like the `if … else` solutions above, `nsDictionaryObject` will be undefined within the `guard` scope. (`swiftObject` will still be defined.)

Comment: Yes, but having `nsDictionaryObject` defined within the `guard` doesn't make sense. What do you think it should be defined as, if the cast to `NSDictionary` fails?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 1.2 you can do it this way:

```
if let nsDictionaryObject = swiftObject as? NSDictionary{} else {

    //your code

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is nsDictionaryObject is lost outside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 1 you could, for instance, use the `else` branch or check for a `nil` result.

```
var swiftObject: AnyObject = ""

if let _ = swiftObject as? NSDictionary { } else {
    println("error")
}

if swiftObject as? NSDictionary == nil {
    println("error")
}
```

Comment: swiftObject will not be valid in your second if, scope will be lost.

Comment: @Aggressor That's not correct. `swiftObject` is declared in the scope surrounding both `if` statements so it will be available inside them as well.

Comment: Yes but declaring it outside defeats the point of getting a 1 line optional chain :(. It looks like until swift 2.0 it can't be done